# Attempt to write to null Array error when passing data to main activity

Tags: java

I am still a beginner and this is my first post here on the forum, sorry if the format of the question is not the right one.
I have an array of Resources in a class called DatabaseTagWalk that I use to find the id of a button in the MainActivity class.

This is the class where I store the id (in the activity_main.xml file i have created 6 buttons and assigned to them the same names as down here

```
public class DatabaseTagWalk {

    int[] iconWalkId;

    public DatabaseTagWalk(){

        iconWalkId = new int[6];

        iconWalkId[0] = R.id.topsightswalk;
        iconWalkId[1] = R.id.literarypariswalk;
        iconWalkId[2] = R.id.secretpassageswalk;
        iconWalkId[3] = R.id.picnictimewalk;
        iconWalkId[4] = R.id.joggitwalk;
        iconWalkId[5] = R.id.deluxegardenswalk;
    }
}
```

And this is the main activity class where I look for the id of the button to set a specific text and to specify the parameters used when the button is clicked

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseWalks listofwalks;
    DatabaseTagWalk tagWalk;
    Button[] buttons;
    int buttonClicked;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listofwalks = new DatabaseWalks();
        tagWalk = new DatabaseTagWalk();

        for (int i = 0; i < listofwalks.walkList.length; i++) {

            buttons[i] = (Button) findViewById(tagWalk.iconWalkId[i]);
            buttons[i].setText(listofwalks.walkList[i].returnWalk());
            setOnClick(buttons[i], tagWalk.iconWalkId[i]);
        }
    }

    public void setOnClick(Button button, final int buttonTag ){
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buttonClicked = buttonTag;
                Intent startingGame = new Intent("android.intent.action.SECONDACTIVITY");
                startingGame.putExtra("buttonTag", buttonClicked);
                startActivity(startingGame);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When i run the app I get the error:

"Attempt to write to null array" in the MainActivity at the line:

```
buttons[i] = (Button) findViewById(tagWalk.iconWalkId[i]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not initialize your `buttons` list. You told that this variable exist, but you did not assign any value.

Change your line:

```
Button[] buttons;
```

to (if you know size - e.g. 10):

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[10];
```

or if wyou would like base on `walkList` size:

```
// After this line
listofwalks = new DatabaseWalks();

// Add new line, because here you know the list size
buttons = new Button[listofwalks.walkList.length];
```

Comment: i have to wait 3 minutes :'D